# How to modify CRUD operations with Entity Framework in .NET MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I need to work out how to do CRUD stuff in an MVC application, passed to me by a former colleague (I don't have any other info, just the application and the database). So I can see there is Model1.edmx and the model browser that contains MyApp.Model>EntityTypes>MyTable representation, and MyAppModel.Store that contains a representation of the table, and the Model1.Designer.cs file which has methods that look like they must be CRUD related (e.g. OnLastNameChanging, OnLastNameChanged). I can run the application and insert and update records to a db table.

What I need to know is where / how do I code other CRUD operations and use Entity Framework to work with WHERE clauses, and do stuff like update another record in a table depending on the value of a given field in the record being inserted or updated.

I've worked with MVC on one other small project but haven't really worked with entities. I'm used to the  WebForms / ADO.NET / stored procedures way of doing things.

Any help gratefully received.

Happy new year!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are using database first approach.

some useful links for Code first approach:
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/793159/Code-First-Approach-in-Entity-Framework-using-Data

other for database first approach

http://www.aspdotnet-pools.com/2014/08/insert-update-delete-operation-in.html

http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-basic-crud-functionality-with-the-entity-framework-in-asp-net-mvc-application

Comment: Thanks, have had a look at the links and will respond again when I've had the chance to work through the stuff in the aspdotnet-pools.com pages. Much appreciated!